# Can we add an entry to /proc/kallsyms?

Tags: linux, kernel, insmod

I wanted to add a function lets say `foo` to my program `my_pgm.c`. I used it by `extern foo();`

When I run Makefile to run `my_pgm.c` it went fine, but as it is not there in `/proc/kallsym` while doing `insmod my_pgm.ko` it throws errror.

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module my_pgm.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

In dmesg it prints like  `Unknown symbol my_pgm (err 0)`

foo defined as part of another file. I took the function pointer foo from there using `nm another_file.ko`. I wanted to insert this pointer entry into `/proc/kallsyms`

My question is can we modify `/proc/kallsyms`? If so how to modify it?(If I edit the file and override it then also changes are not reflecting when I reopen the file)

Comment: You should probably supply a MCVE. I am not following the declarations you are trying to describe. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Modifying `/proc/kallsyms` would be a terrible idea. Instead, make sure that your kernel module `my_pgm` is compiled with accessible **definition** of the function `foo()`. If the function is defined in other kernel module (say, `my_foo`), the simplest way would be compiling both modules (`my_pgm` and `my_foo`) in the single Makefile. Note, that kernel modules cannot call functions, defined in *user space* programs.